# Reading a csv in java is reading only nulls

Tags: java, csv, null

I am trying to read a csv file using opencsv in java. The file is generated by a SAS code. When I try reading the file its giving me all null values even though there are values in the file. However if I open the file and re-save it using save as option the file is read correctly. What can be the solution since I need to automate the process completely without any manual intervention.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Without the code, sample input and output this question is not answerable.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing precisely what the problem is, but I suspect the problem is the file encoding or perhaps there is a byte order mark (BOM) at the beginning indicating that it is unicode.  Your library wouldn't be able to parse it and that would explain your null values.  Resaving it probably removes the BOM or saves it under another character encoding.

Open the file with a hex editor and check byte by byte what the file contains before and after the save.  If you don't see the same values, then that is your reason.

In that case, the solution would be to pass the proper input stream such as a FileReader to the library with the proper character encoding.  I'm not too familiar with SAS but an alternative might be to change the encoding directly of the file being exported to something more reasonable.  [See here for details](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/nlsref/63072/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0utx4w7x4exijn1wt7pk0srrxz5.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I checked opening the file in hex editor before and after saving. The only difference is before saving the Text values appear in double quotes "", however after saving there are no quotes. But when I see the file encoding using : InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileEntry));     System.out.println(r.getEncoding());  I get the same result(i.e. Cp1252) for both cases. Some more suggestions/insights might help!!

Comment: The quotation marks may make a difference then.  Try taking the file that doesn't work and eliminating all but the first line.  Try to open (to verify that it doesn't work), then try manually removing the quotation marks.  Once you've done that, try to open again and verify that it works.  If so, then your problem is that you need to strip quotation marks somehow from the csv file, ideally in the phase of exporting.