# Save as option in JAVA

Tags: java, csv, save

I have a file which is not readable until I open and save it back using save as. There are some formatting issues as it is created using a SAS code. Is there any option for "save as" in java (automated way) as the output format cannot be tweaked (from SAS).

The SAS code generates the csv in this format:

```
"Obs","P10","P20","P30","P40","P50","P60","P70","P80","P90","P91","P92","P93","P94","P95","P96","P97","P98","P99","P100"
"1",.005632791,.007874444,0.010690,0.014358,0.019461,0.027262,0.039370,0.059857,0.10087,0.10837,0.11616,0.12403,0.13478,0.14563,0.15924,0.17487,0.19465,0.22304,0.49123
```

---The Text values are in double quotes

and when the file is re-saved using save as  it becomes:

```
Obs,P10,P20,P30,P40,P50,P60,P70,P80,P90,P91,P92,P93,P94,P95,P96,P97,P98,P99,P100,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,0.005632791,0.007874444,0.01069,0.014358,0.019461,0.027262,0.03937,0.059857,0.10087,0.10837,0.11616,0.12403,0.13478,0.14563,0.15924,0.17487,0.19465,0.22304,0.49123,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a csv in java is reading only nulls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596075/reading-a-csv-in-java-is-reading-only-nulls)

Comment: Yes the issue is same but the problem this time is that I now know that I cannot change the encoding in SAS but I do need to do it at the JAVA end. Could you please help me with some code where I can perform some operation in java to transform the file.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is without your code. So please show us your code. Do you use any library to read and write CSV?

Comment: Yes I am using openCsv

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to write the CSV file then you can use the method [`CSVWriter.writeNext(String\[\] nextLine, boolean applyQuotesToAll)`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#writeNext(java.lang.String[],%20boolean)) with `applyQuotesToAll = true`.

```
Writer writer = new FileWriter(new File("out.csv"));
CSVWriter csvwriter = new CSVWriter(writer, ',', '"');
String[] line = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};
csvwriter.writeNext(line, true);
csvwriter.close();
```

Gives you

```
"a","b","c"
```

Comment: I don't want to write CSV, instead I already have a csv and before reading it with openCsv I need to re save it as which makes my file readable and if I try to read it without re-saving it reads the values as "null"

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "re save"? If you have the file in one format and you want it in another format, then give an example for both formats. And your program wants to transform the data from one format to the other. Then please show us your code. It seems nobody understand what your problem is. If you want our help then it is your job to show us your efforts trying to solve the problem by your own. E.g. read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).